# WebServer Performance Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance, tcp

Recently we moved to a new hosting infrastructure and our web site, every 30 min or so, comes to a halt and then recovers ...

What we noticed by looking at the performance monitor is that while we have no problem with the CPU/Memory/Disk the number of TCP connections suddenly drop sharply from 90-100 to a flat line of 15.
Any ideas??

Server : Windows 2008 R2
Web Server: IIS

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 0):

What are your application pool's settings set to ?
Did you keep the defaults ?

Comment: We didn't change the default settings. How it is related to the dropping of connections?

Comment: There might be settings to recycle workers... just a thought.

Comment: A drop in the number of connections and the server dropping connections are two different things.